# Samsung Galaxy Tab 4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-4

How can I replace the operating system? I am experiencing various problems - especially connectivity - and I suspect the operating system might be corrupted. I would like to clean the device completely - reload the operating system and apps.
Can I do this and if so how?

Comment: If you want to change the OS, or called ROM, you need to ROOT your device.
Google has so many tutorials about this action.

Answer (score 0):

You have to flash the firmware of your device with **ODIN** to reload the operating system and apps. Go to [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/tab-4/general/links-galaxy-tab-4-official-lollipop-5-t3102844) and [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/tab-4/general/links-stock-galaxy-tab-4-firmware-t3013128) thread to download the firmware as per your device. If you didn't find it, please provide more information about your device so that I can show you the right way.